# SOAP API Endpoint not returning object as per applied filter

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am doing this curl request for `Sent Event SOAP API Endpoint`. Even though I am asking for data greater than a specific date, it is still sending me older data, sometimes even 6 months older. Clearly this filter is not working. What is the correct filter so that i do not get any past data ?

```
curl -X POST --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <fueloauth>****</fueloauth>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>SentEvent</ObjectType>
                <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
                <Properties>EventType</Properties>
                <Properties>SendID</Properties>
                <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
                <Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>EventDate</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>greaterThan</SimpleOperator>
                    <DateValue>2019-03-24T10:07:59Z</DateValue>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
' -H 'Accept: text/xml' -H 'SOAPAction: Retrieve' -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' -A 'Jersey/2.25.1' 'https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx'
```

[image: Screenshot for the filter result]

Comment: what data you need to get  can you please explain clearly ?

Comment: @pkharries. I want to get Sent Event Data for Email sends. I want the records only belonging to date greater than that mentioned in filter, but even after applying this filter i am getting records older than the mentioned date.

Comment: what is your time default time zone  for your mc account

Comment: i have check with  your code  for me  its working fine i am getting  today data only

Comment: @pkharries the date is just a sample date. For today's date it might be working fine.. you can try some older date.. But I am not doubtful here, this filter is not working..

Comment: The SOAP envelope is 100% correct and is returning expected results for me as well(using a date in the past). Can you share the exact filter that is giving you issues, perhaps it is malformed?

Comment: @Gortonington I have attached the curl request and the sample output screenshot.. Please do a thorough testing for different customers on your end.

Comment: If it is the case that the events come with a delay , IT would be great help if you can let me know what is the maximum duration for this delay.

Comment: I used POSTman for my call and the returned results were all correct. I would verify the soap call outside of your curl process (I recommend POSTman) to verify that the call is working correctly and if it still returns incorrect results, I would talk to SFMC global support about it.

Comment: @Gortonington I am working towards building data pipeline for SFMC customers to help them analyse their data.. POSTMAN won't be helpful. Please talk to global support.

Comment: Shrestha, I am not support for SFMC, I am another end user trying to assist you. YOU need to reach out to support. POSTman would be just for verification, not for continual use. Essentially to rule out that the envelope is the issue so you can explore other parts of your process to see the weak point.

Comment: @Gortonington Oh Okay ! Thank you so much ! Will look for how to get in touch with Global support